# Formatar casas decimais diretamente no comando SQL em Firebird

Tags: sql, cast, firebird

Tenho uma tabela `ESTOQUE` contendo um campo chamado `QTDE`, esse campo tem 3 casas decimais.

Qual seria o comando pra retornar direto do SQL formatado com 3 casas? Pois os valores inteiros estão retornando sem as casas.

Utilizo: Firebird 2.0 / Campo: Decimal(15,3)

Comment: Está dizendo que, mesmo quando faz um `SELECT * FROM ESTOQUE`, os valores inteiros no campo `QTDE` não mostram `.000`?

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, você obtém no seu gerenciador de banco valores com as casas decimais, idependente de ser com zeros ou não, mas no cliente, quando o valor é inteiro, não retorna casas.. é isso?
Se entendi bem, o problema é o cliente mesmo. Dependendo da linguagem de programação usada em seu programa para exibir os dados do banco no lado cliente, é necessário formatar o valor em forma de uma string para ele ser exibido corretamente. Poderia dar mais detalhes de sua aplicação para poder ajudar?

Answer (score 13):

Tente assim:

```
SELECT cast(seu_campo AS NUMERIC(15,3)) FROM sua_tabela
```

Acredito que sua intenção seja mostrar isso na tela entao tente assim:

```
select cast(seu_campo as varchar(10)) from sua_tabela
```

Comment: Ok... mas quando o registro é inteiro ex. 65 ele não transforma para 65,000

Comment: Então tente assim: 
    select cast(qtd as varchar(10)) from estoque

Comment: Em Firebird, `NUMERIC` e `DECIMAL` são exatamente a mesma coisa. http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq340/

Comment: Perfeitoo.. fiz o teste com VarChar e funcionou blezinha..
select cast(seu_campo as varchar(10)) from sua_tabela

Comment: valeu pessoal.. obrigado a todos!

Comment: Por favor Lucioam então marque como respondida sua questão para ajudar os outros usuários.

Comment: @MattJohnson Até onde me lembro isso não é totalmente verdade. http://www.firebase.com.br/fb/artigo.php?id=2019

Comment: @EMBarbosa sim, achei algumas respostas com informações contrárias.

Comment: @MattJohnson enviei um e-mail para o pessoal do Firebird FAQ mencionando a [documentação](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/migration-mssql-data-types.html)

Answer (score 5):

`select format(1.003, 'N', 'pt-br')`  = 1,00
`select format(1.03, 'G', 'pt-br')` = 1,0300
`select format(1.489, 'C', 'pt-br')` = R$ 1,49

Comment: Wagner, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Se puder explicar um pouco melhor sua resposta será de grande ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

Fiz o `select` usando:

```
CAST(CAST(a.CAMPO AS DECIMAL(18,6)) AS VARCHAR(30))
```

Funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 2):

Configurei `Firebird 2.0` aqui no meu sistema, criei uma tabela com campo de `QTDE`, com `DECIMAL(15,3)`. Inseri 4 números, `10.521`, `11.11`, `65`, e `65.88`. Depois disso fiz `SELECT * FROM tabela;`, e voltou com todas as casas necessárias, inclusive `65.000`.

Será que é alguma configuração com o cliente que está usando para fazer o SQL? Eu usei `Database Workbench v4.4.3 Lite, Firebird Edition` para fazer tudo.

Answer (score 2):

Converter Varchar para decimal, antes tem que converter virgula por ponto para que o comando funcione:

```
cast( replace(p.valor_venda,',','.') as decimal(18,6))
```

Faça da forma acima que funciona...

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo no caso de uma `VIEW` que criei:

```
ALTER VIEW vw_Saldos_Clientes as
Select C.ID_Cliente as ID, C.Nome_Cliente as Cliente,
format(C.Saldo, 'C', 'pt-br') as Saldo
FROM dbo.tbl_Clientes C (NoLock)
```

Resultado:

```
1   Rafael Vilaça       R$ 5.720,00
2   Fernanda Fabiana    R$ 2.600,00
3   Renata Mendonça     R$ 2.600,00
4   Lucas Rosa          R$ 2.600,00
5   Luis Fernando       R$ 2.600,00
```

O comando "`format(C.Saldo, 'C', 'pt-br')`" formata o valor `Money` para o tipo da moeda do Brasil (R$)

Espero ter sido claro...
Obrigado...

Comment: Em qual versão do FB? Tem certeza que não é UDF?

Answer (score -1):

Bom amigo fiz da seguinte maneira, busquei até onde quero, depois alimento de novo o banco com o valor que busquei.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
update oepd set 
       pesliq= (SELECT cast(pesliq AS NUMERIC(15,3))as valor FROM e210epd as ori 
                where ori.numemb=oepd.numemb and ori.codlot=oepd.codlot) 
from e210epd as oepd where numemb=14242
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Caro Arlindo, sua resposta esta um pouco complicada de entender, a sua sugestão é fazer um update nos dados? Mas o AP só quer retornar os valores, não vejo sentido para isto, poderia revisar a resposta e explicar os motivos melhor?