# Firebird - função para casas decimais e milhar

Tags: funções, firebird

Existe alguma **função nativa** do Firebird que me retorne o formato moeda igual ao brasileiro ou alguma **stored procedure** que faça esse serviço.

Exemplo: **#.###,##**

- O ponto seria as casas milhar, milhões etc.
- A virgula seria as casas decimais, no caso queria que retornasse duas

No mysql seria assim:

```
select format(<atributo>,2,'de_DE')
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3455/91

Comment: @rray tentei as duas respostas dessa pergunta mas continua me retornando o ponto como separador decimal e nem aparece o separador de milhar :(

Comment: E no caso desse pergunta ele queria somente visualizar 3 casas decimais, não é o mesmo caso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta esse `cast(tb.SEU_FIELD AS NUMERIC(15,4)) as Saldo` ou 
           `cast( replace(tb.SEU_FIELD,',','.') as decimal(18,4))`

Esses são os únicos modos que sei para formatar os números.

Comment: Doutor Estranho, não funcionou, estou rodando o Firebird 2.5

Comment: vou Editar tenta assim:

cast(T1.VALOR_PAGTO AS NUMERIC(15,4)) as Saldo
o ,4 são para quatro casas decimais depois da virgula

Comment: AGORA SIM !!! Uhuu!!!

Comment: Ops falso positivo, eu tava usando IBexpert e o resultado já era padrão portugues Brasil então retornou com a mascara, mas ao jogar assim no php por exemplo ele me retorna um valor tipo assim: 1175.00

Comment: esse é o exemplo que já disseram que resolve, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3455/91 só que não no meu caso

Comment: Fiz o teste aqui e funciona. Não sei no PHP mais no Delphi também faz via programação. Provavelmente deve ser alguma coias no PHP que deve está colocando o numero de forma que você não deseja.

Comment: usei o DBeaver para acessar o banco de dados e deu certo, pode ser alguma coisa no PHP mesmo